# thread 1 : EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP. subcode = 0x0)

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to change a UIIMageView in another ViewController according to the user's choices. but i get the annoying error! what am I missing?

```
import UIKit
```

class StarbucksRefreshersBeverages: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

```
@IBAction func doneButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
var drink = "blah"

var refreshersDrinks = ["Cool Lime Starbucks Refreshers", "Valencia Orange Starbucks Refreshers", "Verry Berry Hibiscus Starbucks Refreshers"]

var refresherDrink = "blahblah"


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return refreshersDrinks.count

}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "starbucksRefreshersPrototypeCell")

    cell.textLabel?.text = refreshersDrinks[indexPath.row]

    return cell


}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


    self.refresherDrink = refreshersDrinks[indexPath.row]

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("starbucksRefreshersToImageViewSegue", sender: self)



}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {


    var detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as RefreshersImageView

    detailViewController.refresherDrink = self.refresherDrink

    if self.refresherDrink == "Cool Lime Starbucks Refreshers" {

        detailViewController.refreshersImageView.image! == UIImage( contentsOfFile: "coolLime.png")!


    }

    if self.refresherDrink == "Valencia Orange Starbucks Refreshers" {


        detailViewController.refreshersImageView == UIImage(contentsOfFile: "valenciaOrange.png")

    }


}
```

}

I have looked to the other's questions but understood nothing :( please help me. and btw i am really new to programming and I am only 15 :) so please be understanding in the comments and please answer it the way that i will be able to understand. 
very much appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: Are you able to navigate to detailViewController? And if yes did you get the value of detailViewController.refresherDrink in detailViewController. Post your detailViewController also.

Comment: also welcome to SO. When asking stuff, try to follow up on comments and answers. Report back on results, etc...